# Pure virtual overload operator in Boost.Python wrapper

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I'm writing a wrapper class for an abstract base class, the base class has a couple of pure virtual methods and an overloaded operator, if I compile with the overloaded operator I get the following error:

```
cannot allocate an object of abstract type
```

Even though I implement the overloaded operator in my wrapper class, somehow Boost.Python still insists that it is not implemented, any clue ?

This is what my code looks like:

```
//abstract base class
class Test
{
    public:
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
    virtual bool operator==(const Test rhs) = 0;
};

//wrapper class
struct TestWrapper: Test, wrapper<Test>
{
    public:
    void start()
    {
        this->get_override("start")();
    }
    void stop()
    {
        this->get_override("stop")();
    }

    bool operator==(const Test& rhs)
    {
        return this->get_override("operator==")(rhs);
    }

};

//boost python module
class_<TestWrapper, boost::noncopyable>("Test")
    .def("start", pure_virtual(&Test::start) )
    .def("stop", pure_virtual(&Test::stop) )
    .def("operator==", pure_virtual(&Test::operator==))
;
```

Edit: I'm not even sure this is the right way to do this, I haven't seen any examples like this in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two different signatures:

```
class Test
{
    public:
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
    virtual bool operator==(const Test rhs) = 0;  // takes rhs by value
};
```

In the derived class:

```
bool operator==(const Test& rhs)   // takes rhs by reference
{
    return this->get_override("operator==")(rhs);
}
```

So you're not actually implementing the pure virtual from the base, but rather defining a new function.

Comment: That was the first problem, the other one was that one of the functions was a constant member, you made me realize that too, so thank you so much :)